# Android Google Map API v2 = Non full screen Map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to add Google Map API v2 to my app and having a bit of difficulty. I want the map to not take up the full screen but rather just be a certain size that I'll determine. There will be other things on the view besides just this map.

Currently I have the following code, and it just keeps showing me a blank map. I believe this is because I guess I'm mixing v1 and v2 properties. I don't think this is a key problem.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageButton 
     android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/logo_need2buythis"
     android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_local_button"
    style="@style/MainMenuOptionContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/add_location_current"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
           android:id="@+id/add_location_map_view"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class AddLocationFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "com.myapp.android.myapp.AddLocationFragment";

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

public static AddLocationFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    AddLocationFragment fragment = new AddLocationFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_location, parent, false);

    TextView currentLocationText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.add_location_current);

    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.add_location_map_view);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.2137, -77.4358), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}
```

}